# Laravel Saving file posts it as a bin file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Am trying to save a file in laravel but it endsup being saved as a bin file

```
 $file = $request->file('file');
 $name = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')."-".strtotime(Carbon::now()).".".$file->extension();
 $stored =$file-> storeAs('temporary', $name); //save the file to temporary
```

Now the above saves every file as .bin file
When i check

```
$file->extension();
```

Am getting .bin

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `getClientOriginalExtension()` method instead of `extension()`:

```
$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```