# How to STR Replace and echo in laravel

Tags: laravel

Files that are uploaded to my site have their names changed and extention change to bin. So for example a uploaded file will be dfd84848.bin, using the bin file worked fine with modelviewer but im trying to test babylon.js and it doesnt work with .bin only if i change .bin to .glb.

This code `{{uploaded_asset($detailedProduct->cad_file)}}` provides link like `uploads/all/p1YZX9TBc7EmimFx4rXnSFKvVor8EttpOUUpylLL.bin`

I want to change `.bin` to `.glb` and echo it.

i tried this

```
@php
    $previewfile = uploaded_asset($detailedProduct->cad_file);
    $replaced = Str::replace('.bin', '.glb', $previewfile );
@endphp
```

to show i used this `<model url="{$replaced}">` but it never echoed url

Edit

So now that it echos as name.glb it doesnt work because the file doesnt exist on server. When 3d models such as .glb, .gltf are uploaded they are renamed to .bin i dont know why. The uploader is AizUploadController.php

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{{ $replaced }}` ?

Comment: this works thanks im new to this, the new problem i have now is that the file dgdgdgdf434.glb doesnt exist how can i fix this?

Comment: What do you really need? Replace string, does not mean the file is also available.

Comment: when i upload stl, glb, files they are named .bin, i dont know why. Other files stay as .png , .zip, .pdf but for these 3d model files they get renamed. So the problem is when i try to load with correct extension it doesnt work.

Comment: I understand your situation. But your current question does not represent the real issue. We recommend that you edit your question so we can answer it.

Comment: Also, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48385595/984422

Comment: You should post another question which reflects your new problem

Comment: it does use https://pastebin.com/7Q3MNNUF getClientOriginalExtension() , also i cant add another question for 90 mins

Comment: the pastebin is the file responsible for the uploads, and renaming the file and saving them. What do i need to change to ensure that atleast .glb and .gltf files are saved with correct extension

Comment: 90 minutes have passed. You can add a new question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To echo a value you should use double curly braces:

`<model url="{{ $replaced }}">`

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-data